# Content-Security-Policy : Script-src 'self' not working in Firefox 78 Windows NT 10 for loading scripts from the same origin

Tags: javascript, firefox, windows-10, content-security-policy, websecurity

We have the below CSP Report Only policy set which allows all the scripts to load from the same origin using 'Self'.
But in browser Firefox 78 on Windows NT 10 it still reports loading script from same origin as error.

```
CspReport {
            blockedUri='https://staging.global.com/app/ui/home/home.js', 
            documentUri='https://staging.global.com/app/ui/home/home.html', 
            violatedDirective='script-src'
            disposition='null', 
            effectiveDirective='null', 
            originalPolicy='default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'  https://www.google-analytics.com; font-src 'self' data: https://fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://ssl.gstatic.com https://www.gstatic.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'  https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://tagmanager.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://tagmanager.google.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; manifest-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self';
            report-uri /app/report
          }
```

Browser details :

```
 userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
```

CSP Policy :

```
'default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline;
```

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show content of the "original Policy" field? And is this occurred in your browser(you can to look source err msg in dev console) or some users and you only can watch it in violation reports?

Comment: @granty I have added the originalPolicy. Please check. It is reported from the customer browser as we have enabled CSP in Report Only mode. We are unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

You have added very helpful fields, therefore we can make investigation using Sherlock Holmes deduction method.

1. `disposition='null'` means we have a deal with **not** CSP3-browser. The `disposition` field was introduced in CSP3 only and can be [either "enforce" or "report"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#policy-disposition).
2. `violatedDirective='script-src'` + `effectiveDirective='null'` confirms guessing in para 1 above.  According to [CSP3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#ref-for-dom-event-composed), *both effectiveDirective and violatedDirective are the same value. This is intentional to maintain backwards compatibility.*

Hence this violation report was definitely sent by CSP2 browser(or even CSP1). But Mozilla Firefox v78 have totally supports CSP3.
This means that you visitor did substitute user agent for some reason.

Your CSP is correct, legal Firefox browser should not send any report.

My guess is we have a deal with parser-bot which uses a legacy browser emulator. If you log an IP-addresses in reports you can check it via whois service to belongs sone public hosting.
Also "country by IP" could help to clear is it your real customer or not.

**But one thing** remains unclear - your apps have password protected access. Without auth the access is blocked on page which has not any CSP header.

> 

Anyway for older browser support you can explicitly add https://staging.global.com into policy:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://staging.global.com;
```

and observe if this violation disappears or not.